# Benefits to using a FIleHandle vs a filepath as a String in Node.js

Tags: node.js

Node.js offers a `fs` API as well as `fs/promises` API. My question today will be specific to the `fs/promises` API, though I am sure the behaviour is the same between both.

When using the `writeFile` function (or many other functions in that API), you have the option of specifying the file as either a filepath as a string, or through a FileHandle created through a function like `open()`.

Clearly, it is easier and more concise to simply use a path vs a FileHandle:

```
let path = '/path/to/my/file'
let handle = await open(path, 'a')
await writeFile(handle, "Hello World");

[... versus...]
let path = '/path/to/my/file'
await writeFile(path, "Hello World");
```

Both versions run without issue. My question is what are the advantages to opening the file manually using a `FileHandle` vs letting node do it w/ the filepath?

Documentation in question: https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fspromiseswritefilefile-data-options

Comment: Wouldn't the functions throw errors in that case, even if the path is not a FileHandle?

Comment: The function would throw an error in both cases yes but it is more about at which point you want to catch it and handle it.

Answer (score 0):

In general, both accomplish the same thing and only the syntax is different. If we implement it with FileHandle, this is what it would look like.

```
async function openFile(path) {
    let fileHandle;
    try {
        fileHandle = await fsPromises.open(path, 'r');
        console.log(`opened ${path}, file descriptor is ${fileHandle.fd}`);
        const data = fileHandle.read()
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err.message);
    } finally {
        fileHandle?.close();
    }
}
```

Having to have a `finally` clause and an external variable to escape the `try {}` scope is definitely less ergonomic.